# Network Security: Lan Manager Authentication Level

Tags: security, group-policy, windows

I'm a  little bit confused by the explanation provided for the setting "Network Security: LAN Manager AUthentication Level" in group policies.
The provided explanation only talks about clients and domain controllers.
I'd like to know how the provided settings work for servers which are not domain controllers?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Servers which are not domain controllers *are* clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers, as I understand it, to the use of NTLM or LM as an authentication method.  NTLM is pass-the-hash authentication, which is about as good as cleartext; if you like security you should disable it.  It is the kind of thing that you should only enable if you have some compelling operational reason to need NTLM or LM authentication.  Only ancient things need this; you should either not set this option, or set it to "Send NTLMv2 response only refuse LM & NTLM" unless you have windows 2000 or earlier in your environment for some reason.

Servers are servers in some contexts, and clients in others.  When it comes to user authentication, only domain controllers are servers and everything else is a client (kind of; in NTLM yes; see also: kerberos, where it's more complex than that).